# printing strings with pointer arithmetics

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to print random words with the use of rand().
I think that I've made a mistake on the pointer arithmetic since I get a weird output.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

    int main ()
    {
        srand(time(0));
        const int randomBit = rand() % 2;
        char * sz[] ={"good", "bad"};
    
        switch (randomBit)
        {
        case 0:
            for (char *i=*sz; *i<(sz+3); i++)
            {
                printf("%c", *i);
            }
            break;
    
        case 1:
            for (char *i=*(sz+3); *i!=0x0; i++)
            {
                printf("%c", *i);
            }
        break;
        
        default:
            break;
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

What's my mistake?
Thank you.

Comment: This code is pain to read. Why aren't you printing the whole strings?

Comment: You can write unit tests to ensure for some extent that logic is correct

Comment: You init *i to *sz, then you check to see if *i is less than (sz+3)

Comment: @sirmeowsalot
 Describe what you are trying to output.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well in that case either the word "good" or "bad" depending if a 0 or 1 got generated.

Comment: @sirmeowsalot And what does the magic number 3 in this expression *i<(sz+3) mean?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oops should've been a <=. But shouldn't *sz point at the first character (g)? my thought was that I could print it like that.

Comment: @Gerhardh, `sz[0]` and `*sz` are indeed equivalent, and they both point to characters.  They have type `char *`.  It is `sz` and forms such as `sz + 0` that point to pointers to `char`.

Comment: sirmeowsalot 1) "since I get a weird output." and not posting that output nor expected output attracts down-votes.  Best to post input used (none here), output seen, output expected.  2) Save time, enable all compiler warnings to catch problems like with `*i<(sz+3)`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you are right. My wording was wrong. They are pointing to char but OP seems to expect `*sz` to be a `char`.

Comment: I don't see that, @Gerhardh.  They use, for example, `char *i=*sz`, which is type-correct, and then they treat `*i` as a `char`, which is also type-correct.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, that part is correct. But the `+3` seems to count characters in a strange ways which does not fit into the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this declaration ...

> ```
>         char * sz[] ={"good", "bad"};
> ```

... this code has undefined behavior:

> ```
>             for (char *i=*(sz+3); *i!=0x0; i++)
> ```

The expression `*(sz+3)` is equivalent to `sz[3]`, but array `sz` has only two elements, so the maximum index is 1.

Likewise, the expression `*sz` is equivalent to `sz[0]`.  That one is semantically ok but stylistically poor.  Likewise stylistically poor is splitting out two separate cases when you could instead cover both with the same code by using `sz[randomBit]` to select which string to print.

Furthermore, it is unclear why you are printing character by character.  Perhaps that's part of the assignment, but in the real world a programmer would probably write ...

```
    printf("%s", sz[randomBit]);
```

... instead of that entire `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incredibly complicated (and wrong).

What's wrong with this:

```
int main()
{
  srand(time(0));
  const int randomBit = rand() % 2;
  char* sz[] = { "good", "bad" };

  printf("%s\n", sz[randomBit]);    
  return 0;
}
```

or if you are not allowed to use the `%s` format specifier as part of your assignement:

```
  for (char* i = sz[randomBit]; *i != 0;  i++)
  {
    printf("%c", *i);  // or putchar(*i);
  }
```

Comment: In the latter case, the printf mechanism is overkill where putchar would suffice.

Comment: @stark that's true, but I wanted to stay close to the OP's code.